# How To install cached_network_image package with new version of flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to install Cached_network_image pakcage on my flutter project but this throwing an error how I can solve this ( When I delete Cached_network_image the project works fine ) , I Don't Know how to solve this , any help please ?  :

```
Running "flutter pub get" in my_app...                      
Because flutter_cache_manager >=2.0.0-beta <2.1.2 depends on path_provider ^1.6.18 and 
flutter_cache_manager >=2.1.2 <3.0.0-nullsafety.0 depends on image >=2.1.18 <4.0.0, 
flutter_cache_manager >=2.0.0-beta <3.0.0-nullsafety.0 requires path_provider ^1.6.18 or image 
>=2.1.18 <4.0.0.
And because image >=3.0.0-nullsafety.0 <3.0.1 depends on xml ^5.0.0-nullsafety.1 and image >=3.0.1 
depends on xml ^5.0.0, flutter_cache_manager >=2.0.0-beta <3.0.0-nullsafety.0 requires path_provider 
^1.6.18 or xml ^5.0.0-nullsafety.1 or image >=2.1.18 <3.0.0-nullsafety.0.

 And because image >=2.1.14 <3.0.0-nullsafety.0 depends on archive ^2.0.0 which depends on crypto 
^2.0.0, flutter_cache_manager >=2.0.0-beta <3.0.0-nullsafety.0 requires path_provider ^1.6.18 or xml 
^5.0.0-nullsafety.1 or crypto ^2.0.0.

And because google_fonts 2.0.0 depends on both path_provider ^2.0.0 and crypto ^3.0.0, if 
flutter_cache_manager >=2.0.0-beta <3.0.0-nullsafety.0 and google_fonts 2.0.0 then xml ^5.0.0- 
nullsafety.1.

   Because no versions of flutter_svg match >0.19.3 <0.20.0 and flutter_svg 0.19.3 depends on xml 
  ^4.2.0, flutter_svg ^0.19.3 requires xml ^4.2.0.

Thus, one of flutter_svg ^0.19.3 or flutter_cache_manager >=2.0.0-beta <3.0.0-nullsafety.0 or 
 google_fonts 2.0.0 must be false.

And because cached_network_image >=2.5.0 <3.0.0-nullsafety depends on flutter_cache_manager ^2.1.0, 
 one of flutter_svg ^0.19.3 or google_fonts 2.0.0 or cached_network_image >=2.5.0 <3.0.0-nullsafety 
  must be false.

And because no versions of google_fonts match >2.0.0 <3.0.0 and dentel_app depends on google_fonts 
^2.0.0, flutter_svg ^0.19.3 is incompatible with cached_network_image >=2.5.0 <3.0.0-nullsafety.

 So, because my_app depends on both flutter_svg ^0.19.3 and cached_network_image ^2.5.1, version 
   solving failed.
    pub get failed (1; So, because my_app depends on both flutter_svg ^0.19.3 and 
    cached_network_image ^2.5.1, version solving failed.)
       exit code 1
```

pubspec.yaml :

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
 flutter:
sdk: flutter
google_fonts: ^2.0.0
flutter_icons: ^1.1.0
http: ^0.13.1
firebase_auth: ^1.0.1
firebase_core: ^1.0.2
cloud_firestore: ^1.0.3
firebase_storage: ^8.0.1
image_picker: ^0.7.3
flutter_signin_button: ^1.1.0
font_awesome_flutter: ^8.2.0
flutter_screenutil: ^4.0.4
line_awesome_icons: ^1.0.4+2
flutter_svg: ^0.19.3
bubble: ^1.2.1
webview_flutter: ^2.0.2
```

cached_network_image: ^2.5.1

Comment: I had the same issue.it fix by downgrading from http ^1.1.0 to http ^0.13.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

`cached_network_image: ^3.0.0-nullsafety`

and then if it doesn't work, use this with it also:
`flutter_svg: ^0.21.0-nullsafety.0`